# how to pass variable value to outside of URLSession async - swift 3

Tags: swift, asynchronous

I have this code :

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error!)
        return    
    }    
    do {        
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

        if let parseJSON = json {        
            let getDetail = parseJSON["detail"] as? String

            returnDetail = getDetail!.base64Decoded()        
        } // parse json end    
    } // do end                
    catch {         
        print(error)    
    }    
} // let task end
```

`returnDetail` has been defined previously. I did anything to set `returnDetail` value to `getDetail!.base64Decoded()` but it only works inside `let task = ...`

How can I pass it to the outer scope?

Comment: Are you sure that     condition  if let parseJSON = json    is fire

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish everything works fine just inside let task = ... I have checked by printing at every blobk

Comment: Your problem most probably is that this is an asynchronous function and you are trying to access `returnDetail` before the function would return. Please explain what you want to do with it, give some more context and then you can get an exact answer on how to solve this issue. Some general advice: don't use `mutableContainers`, in Swift it has no effect and use native Swift objects when available, such as `Dictionary` instead of `NSDictionary`.

Comment: what is the definition of returnDetail

Comment: @DávidPásztor this block (let task = ...) is a part of function that send HTTP request and gets the returned array and parses it. parseJSON["detail"] contains returned string from php. finally this whole function should return parseJSON["detail"] to where it has been called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several methods to tackle the issue of returning a value from inside an asynchronous function. One of them is to wrap the asynchronous network call inside a function and make it return a completionHandler.

Some general advice: don't use force unwrapping unless you are 100% sure that your optional value won't be `nil`. With network requests, the `data` can be nil even if there's no error, so never force unwrap `data`, use safe unwrapping with `if let` or `guard let`. Don't use `.mutableContainers` in Swift when parsing a JSON value, since it has no effect. The mutability of the parsed JSON object is decided by using the `let` or `var` keyword to declare the variable holding it. Also don't use `NSDictionary`, use its native Swift counterpart, Dictionary (`[String:Any]` is a shorthand for the type `Dictionary<String,Any>`).

```
func getDetail(withRequest request: URLRequest, withCompletion completion: @escaping (String?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        if error != nil {
            completion(nil, error)
            return    
        }    
        else if let data = data {
            do {        
                guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:Any] else {completion(nil, nil);return}      
                guard let details = json["detail"] as? String else {completion(nil, nil);return}
                completion(details, nil)        
            }                  
            catch {         
                completion(nil, error)  
            }
        }   
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Then you can call this function by

```
getDetail(withRequest: request, withCompletion: { detail, error in
    if error != nil {
        //handle error
    } else if detail = detail {
        //You can use detail here
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a completion handler.

```
func foo(withCompletion completion: (String?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        if error != nil {
            completion(nil, error)
            return    
        }    

        do {        
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

            if let parseJSON = json {        
                let details = parseJSON["detail"] as? String

                completion(details, nil)        
            } // parse json end    
        } // do end                
        catch {         
            completion(nil, error)  
        }   
    } // let task end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you use CallBack(Clourse) of Swift to return data when getDetail have data.