# Firestore Query Swift 4.0 Missing Return

Tags: swift, return, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following query;

```
fileprivate func observeQuery() {
    guard let query = query else { return }
    stopObserving()

    listener = query.addSnapshotListener({ [unowned self] (snapshot, error) in
        guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }
        let models = snapshot.documents.map({ (document) -> Post in
            if let model = Post(dictionary: document.data()) {
                return model
            } else {
                print(error as Any)
            }
        }) //here
        self.posts = models
        self.documents = snapshot.documents
    })
}
```

I am getting "Missing return in a closure expected to return 'Post'" mentioned as "//here" in the code.  I have return model which is of type Post and I cannot access model after the closure.  I have used the GitHub files here;
[Firestore GitHub iOS Quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios)

This error doesn't make sense to me can someone please shed some light on the matter?

Many thanks as always.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to pass variable value to outside of URLSession async - swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45836297/how-to-pass-variable-value-to-outside-of-urlsession-async-swift-3). Your issue is essentially the same. You cannot return values from an async method with the synchronous `return` keyword.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Are you sure that's the cause? On a quick scan I have the impression that the `snapshot.documents.map` closure simply isn't returning anything in the `else` block.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen you are right, for some reason I thought OP wanted to return the value from the whole async function, not just from inside the `map` closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that not all code branches return inside the closure of your `map` statement. You should change `map` to `flatMap`, this way you can also get rid of the if statement by simply returning the failable initializer's result inside your closure, since `flatMap` will filter out all `nil` return values.

```
let models = snapshot.documents.flatMap({ document in Post(dictionary: document.data())})
```

Comment: Adding .flatMap instad of .map fixes this issue however, im still not getting any snapshot.  I will post another question for this.